# Spivak alternative limit solution fallacy

Tags: limits

I can't find where the fallacy of the following proof lies!
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from Spivak's own answer book:

“How do we know that $\sqrt{a^2-\epsilon}$ and $\sqrt{a^2+\epsilon}$ exist!? In Chapter 7 we prove (Theorem 8) that every positive number has a square root, but the proof of this theorem uses the fact that $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous, which is essentially what we are trying to prove.”

Comment: Why is the continuity involved? Continuity states if the value of the function is equal to the limit of the function! So why should we show that if $x^2=a$ then $x= /sqrt{a}$ only if $x^2$ is continuous?

Comment: I mean, in order to prove that the $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous we have to previously know that $f(a)=a^2$

Comment: What he's doing in Chapter 7 is to use the mean value theorem in order to show that (the *continuous*) function $f(x)=x^2$ takes on every positive value. Before you know that fact, the use of the square root symbol is meaningless.